# Genemu don't shows autocomplete on Sonata

Tags: symfony, autocomplete, jquery-select2, sonata-admin

I'm trying to use genemu select2 autocomplete on a Sonata Admin with synmfony 2.3.

I follow the instructions from here https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/select2/index.md

Genemu version "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*" => for Symfony 2.3
Bundle added on Appkernel
Assets of Select2 included on layout template (overriding it)

Everything seems to be well configured, indeed if i use genemu_jqueryselect2_country, it replace the data from de select with countries... but not shows any autocomplete.

```
->add('codigo_postal', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array('label' => 'Código postal', 'class' => 'MyBundle\CodigoPostal', 'property' => 'codigo'))
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the javascript call : {{ form_javascript(form) }} in the base admin template (that extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig') ?

Comment: I create a standard_layout.html.twig on Resources/views, wheres is base admin template to set this call?

Comment: See this : https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/template.md
In the standard_layout i add this (end the same for stylesheet) : 
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% if form is defined %}{{ form_javascript(form) }}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}